# How to access BERT intermediate layer outputs in TF Hub Module?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model, tensorflow-hub

Does anybody know a way to access the outputs of the intermediate layers from BERT's hosted models on Tensorflow Hub?

The model is hosted [here](https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1). I have explored the meta graph and found the only signatures available are "tokens, "tokenization_info", and "mlm". The first two are illustrated in the [examples on github](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb), and the masked language model signature doesn't help much. Some models like inception allow you to access all of the intermediate layers, but not this one.

Right now, all I can think of to do is:

1. Run `[i.values() for i in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()]` to get the names of the tensors, find the ones I want (out of thousands) then
2. `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(name_of_the_tensor)` to access the values and stitch them together and connect them to my downstream layers.

Anybody know a cleaner solution with Tensorflow?

Comment: Probably the way you hacked is the only way to read the intermediate layer since they are not exposed through the hub signature. Another option is to propose a feature request asking for other outputs on github.

Comment: Thanks! That's kind of what I thought. I'll probably propose a feature request. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the more I read in BERT literature, the more it seems there are many benefits from these other layers being concatenated.

Comment: Yeah, I see some people (some particular domain/use case), using intermediate layer is helpful. but your mileage may vary. Anyway, it is worth a try.

Comment: Can you please post elaborate code to pull out the layer features? I am getting an error `InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float`

Comment: checkout this issue @sourabhxiii https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/290

Answer (score 1):

BERT is one of the latest achievements in the transformer language models area. Unlike predecessors BERT can achieve bidirectional architecture using MLM (Masked Language Model). This provides better contextualized word / sentence embedding for a variety of NLP solutions. As for general usage. Bert provides SOTA embeds with its last layer. But for research purposes, it is also advised to consider intermediate layers for text representations. The picture below shows the effect of the different use-cases with intermediate layers.

[image: Effect of BERT Intermediate Information]

As it can be seen from the picture it is mostly advised to sum last four layers. Summing last four layers gives less embedding dimension compared to concatenation and it results with %0.2 difference. Intermediate layers can be achieved with scripts provided from BERT original GitHub page but implementing this scripts to downstream NLP task requires custom Keras layers. Instead TensorFlow-Hub provides one-line BERT with Keras layer. BERT TensorFlow-Hub solutions are updated on regular basis. First two versions only provided sentence (pooled output) or word (sequence_output). With v3 BERT now provides intermediate layer information. Link to BERT V3 is provided below.

[BERT-LARGE v3 TF-HUB](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_wwm_uncased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/3)

In the given page, section named "Advanced topics" states the following information.

> The intermediate activations of all L=24 Transformer blocks (hidden layers) are returned as a Python list: outputs["encoder_outputs"][i] is a Tensor of shape [batch_size, seq_length, 1024] with the outputs of the i-th Transformer block, for 0 <= i < L. The last value of the list is equal to sequence_output.

In v3, one can achieve intermediate layer information using (encoder_outputs). Intermediate layers are returned as  python lists to carry out concatenation or sum operations or else. Another extension in v3 is that BERT TensorFlow-Hub now provides pre-processor. BERT takes three inputs "input_word_ids, input_mask, and input_type_ids". Pre-processor can take a string as an input and returns required inputs for BERT.

I haven't had a chance to test this approach but if it is not very curicual I recommend using last layer information. BERT is very powerful and GPU-dependent text representator compared to old lookup-table approaches. Common issue that researchers faced with bert is OOM problems with single GPU. To solve this use tf2 with memory growth. I will try to test BERT Hub v3 and give more feedback.